# Excel-VBA transfers incorrect date values from SAS to Excel-sheet

Tags: vba, excel, date, sas

My VBA code transfers a SAS-table to Excel-sheet via `ADODB.Connection` and `"SAS.LocalProvider.1"`. Two SAS-columns are date in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`, like `2015-09-01` and `2015-09-30`.

I am also using `format` for those columns in my VBA-code like `Sheet2.Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"`. Then it is supposed to convert the whole column into the correct date format.

However, in the end, I get date values in the Excel-sheet like `1955-08-31` and `1955-09-29` instead of `2015-09-01` and `2015-09-30`.

I checked the SAS-table and both columns are `numeric` and the format is `date` as `YYDDMM10.`.

I wrote in the VBA code as `YYMMDD` and `YY-MM-DD` as it is shown in the SAS-format, but it didn't help. It still gave the same year as 1955 (or only 55).

In the code, you can see that I tried to change the format "before the table-transer". But also I tried it "after the table-transfer" as well, but I got exactly the same result.

```
Public Sub SASTransfer()
  Dim rTarget1 As Range: Set rTarget1 = Sheet2.Range("A2")
  Dim sSasTable1 As String: sSasTable1 = SASOutputPath & "\" & SASOutput1 & ".sas7bdat"

    Sheet2.Range(Range("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD" ' This should change the format of the whole C-column
    Sheet2.Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

    Dim con1 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
    con1.Provider = "SAS.LocalProvider.1"
    con1.Open
    rs1.Open sSasTable1, con1, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, ADODB.adCmdTableDirect
    rTarget1.CopyFromRecordset rs1
    rs1.Close
    Set rs1 = Nothing
    con1.Close
    Set con1 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, the reason you are seeing this is that SAS stores dates as the number of days between 1 Jan 1960 and the date in question, whereas Excel stores them as the number of days after 31/12/1899.

Comment: @Rory, no it's not. It's because excel is expecting one date format and sas is providing another.

Comment: @NickDewitt So it's entirely coincidental that the number of days difference in the resulting dates would be explained perfectly by that? How odd.

Comment: @rory oh yeah fair point, sorry rushed that comment on my way out of work - 1960 Base dates and 1900 based dates are technically different formats though ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- SAS uses 1/1/1960 as its reference date for day 0.
- Excel uses 1/0/1900 (i.e. 12/31/1899) as its reference date for day 0.

The number of days between 1/1/1960 and 12/31/1899 is 21,916.

Since you're going from SAS to Excel, add 21916 to the SAS date.

```
data excel_export;
     set have;
     Excel_Date = SAS_Date + 21916;
     format Excel_Date mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks. It is not a perfect solution, but at least it is a solution. Only this method worked.

Comment: 21,916 is the number of days Microsoft thinks is between 31st Dec 1899 and 1st Jan 1960 (so is the correct number to use here).  They include 29th Feb 1900, however this wasn't a leap year and therefore that date shouldn't exist.  I got caught out with this many years ago when converting from another package using the 1900 date system!  The other package had 1st Jan 1900 set as 0, so I ended up 2 days different to Microsoft.

Comment: For some reason, Excel and SAS will both do this from time to time. I can't determine why it happens, but occasionally I'll be importing/exporting some Excel data and need to do something like this. I'm guessing it has something to do with the column type in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the display format in excel will not change how it recognises the value in the cell.

You need to set the date format on the adodb connection, not on the cells in the worksheet.

see http://support.sas.com/documentation/tools/oledb/ddh001.htm

You need to add a property to the recordset to tell it how to format the date as it is being imported (replace datecolumnname with the name of your date column, you can define multiple columns by delimiting the list with a comma.

```
rst.Properties("SAS Formats") = "datecolumnname=ddmmyy8."
```

This will import the date in the format dd/mm/yyyy.

You will need to set the format of the incoming data to match your locale settings, then excel will interpret the date correctly and display it as you have set in your cell format.

**EDIT 1**

SAS provides the following example to extract formatted data, they suggest setting the activeconnection of the recordset before executing the query:

```
' obConnection is an open Connection object.
Dim obRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

obRecordset.ActiveConnection = obConnection
obRecordset.Properties("SAS Formats") = "saledate=mmddyy8.,+price=dollar8.2."

' The second parameter on the Open method must remain empty.
obRecordset.Open "sales", , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdTableDirect
```

Comment: Both SAS and Excel uses integers for Dates, SAS' 0 being `1960-01-01`, Excel's being `1900-01-00`. I recommend the [SI Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for interfaces, Excel will recognize it regardless of your regional settings

Comment: if your regional is UK, and you are putting a string date in US format, it will get confused some of the time depending on whether the day number is less than or equal to 12.

Comment: I tried as you wrote like `rs1.Properties("SAS Formats") = "PeriodFrom=ddmmyy8."`, but it gives error like it can't find the object (I don't know what it means with the object). `rs1` is the name of the recordset and `PeriodFrom` is the name of the date column.

Comment: @NickDewitt sorry, I had to go away. The error message is `Run Time Error 3265 - Item not found in this collection` for the line `rs1.Properties("SAS Formats") = "PeriodFrom=ddmmyy8."`. As I wrote, `rs1` is the name of the recordset and `PeriodFrom` is the name of the SAS-column.

Comment: bear with me trying to log into a server with sas on it so I can test this for you. vpn is playing up from home!

Comment: Run Time Error 3265 means that the column doesn't exist. Sas table columns have both a name and a description, can you double check that you are referring to the name, not the description and then also try it all in lower case?

Comment: Now I checked the column properties in SAS. The name is `PeriodFrom` and the label is completely empy. Shouldn't it be enough just to have a column name?

Comment: Can you check how the recordset is seeing the column names? remove the 'SAS Formats' line, and open the table as you were, then loop the fields and print the names:     'For Each fld In rs1.Fields
        Debug.Print fld.Name
    Next fld'

Comment: @NickDewitt Now it transfers with your method, but unfortunately it ends up in excel-sheet as `1955-08-31` even if I only used the line `rs1.Properties("SAS Formats") = "PeriodFrom=YYMMDD10."`. I wrote `YYMMDD10.` because it is like that in SAS. I think I should consider about other solutions.

Comment: YYMMDD10 will provide it in the format '2015-09-01'. Can you try putting a + before the format ("+datecolumnname=ddmmyy8."), then it should output both the formatted and unformatted columns.

Comment: I wrote `"+PeriodFrom=ddmmyy8."` and `"+PeriodFrom=yymmdd10."`, both gave the same result as `1955-08-31`. I searched the SAS-documentation, there is only information about adding 21916 to the date to convert from SAS to Excel [SAS-Doc](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/068-29.pdf)

Comment: Without looking at your files directly, I can't say what you were doing wrong. I have tested this with Excel 2010 and SAS V9 this morning and it works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 2):

From [About SAS Date, Time, and Datetime Values](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002200738.htm):

> SAS date value is a value that represents the number of days between January 1, 1960, and a specified date. SAS can perform calculations on dates ranging from A.D. 1582 to A.D. 19,900. Dates before January 1, 1960, are negative numbers; dates after are positive numbers.

If you cannot find a conversion factor, you may wish to convert the actual numerically based dates to strings-that-look-like-dates in the local computer's MDY vs DMY regional format and allow Excel to process them on-the-fly. Not the best solution but a numerical date will always be out by 60 years without a conversion factor as Excel dates are represented by 1 for every day past Dec 31, 1899.